# Mechanics problem. I solve it with 2 methods and get 2 different answers.

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

The problem: (I'm having trouble with (ii) but I listed (i) because one of the answers depend on it)

Drawing it out would help.

> The point O is 20m above horizontal ground. A particle is projected
>   from O with velocity 35 m/s at an angle of elevation 45 degrees above
>   the horizontal, and it moves freely under gravity. The particle hits
>   the ground at the point A. Find:

---

> (i) the height above the ground of the highest point of the path of
>   the particle.

$v=u+at$ ... $u=35sin(45)$ ... $v=0$ ... $a=-10$ (gravitational force)

$0=35sin(45)-10t$ ... $t~= 2.47$

$s=ut+0.5at^2$ ... $s=35sin(45)*2.47-5(2.47)^2$

$s=30.6+20~=50.6$

(we added +20 in the end since O is 20 meters above the ground).

...Correct. The answer key says that this is the correct answer.

> (ii) the time taken for the particle to travel from O to A.

okay

**1st method of solution:**

I considered the particle's motion from "the highest point" to A, got out the time and then added 2.47s to the answer

$s=ut+0.5at^2$ ... $s=-50.6$ ... $a=-10$ ... $u=0$

$-50.6=-5t^2$ $t=\sqrt(50.7/5)$ $t~=3.18$

$3.18+2.47=5.66s$

...Correct. The answer key says that this is the correct answer.

**2nd method of solution:**

I considered the particle's motion from O till A.

$s=ut+0.5at^2$ ... <s>**s=-30.6**</s> ... $u=35sin(45)$ ... $a=-10$

$-30.6=35sin(45)t-5t^2$ ... $5t^2-35sin(45)t-30.6=0$

That's a quadratic equation! *After solving it with the quadratic formula (I used the calculator's "quadratic formula solver") I get the positive answer to be:*

$t=5.97$s

There are 0.3 seconds extra.

Where's my mistake? Maybe it's an accuracy issue? (due to approximations and so) What did I do wrong?

*p.s: sometimes the answer key has mistakes, don't count on it much* Thanks in advance :)

**edit**: The mistake was $s=-30.6$. The correct displacement value is $s=-20$ that's all! :D

Comment: Pls format your answer using the math code! I just tried it but it's a bit hard

Comment: I would if I could. This is my first question on this site. I'll try :)

Comment: thx, if you need some help I can edit the first formula so you know how to do the rest

Comment: I'm formatting it right now. seems easy :D just hang on a minute

Comment: how do I make a square root?

Comment: like $\sqrt{2}$ its done `\sqrt{2}`

Comment: Ok I just calculated you're first method and its defnetly correct!

Comment: How d'you get $s=-30.6$ the second way?

Comment: HOORAAAAAAAAAAAY!!! YOU GOT MY MISTAKE :D :D :D :D It's supposed to be -20. THANKS ALOT PAL!!! :D :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: ok thx! I was wondering so much I just posted how to do it! Am I correct its $187.5m$? Edit: ah fail it wasn't asked for that but the time is $7.576$

Comment: Please post and accept your answer so this doesn't stay in the unanswered queue.  I think you have to wait a bit to accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @mjb4 ummm the correct time is 5.66 seconds :D

Comment: @RossMillikan okay but I hope mjb4 would post the answer as to take the credit :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the particle rises for $t_{r} = 2.47 s$, then it falls again for the same time.
But hang on it is still $20m$ above ground. So we have to calculate how long it will take for the rest.
The Velocity $v_{f}$ for the last $20m$ is exactly the velocity the particle had as you were shooting it upwards (remember this is a parabola)!
So for the movement you will get:

$$ h(t) = 20m-35\sin(45°)t-\frac{10}{2}t^2 = 0 \quad\Rightarrow \quad t^2+\frac{2\cdot 24.75}{10}t-20 =0 $$

Solving this gives you one rubish solution (it's negative and one positiv, thats *the* one!):
$$ t_1 = -\frac{35\sin(45°)}{2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{35\sin(45°)}{2}\right)^2+20} = 0.7833 s $$

So the total flight time is:
$$ T = 2t_r+t_1 = 5.723 $$

You're sure are right with 5.66 seconds

Comment: yes I'm definitely sure that the correct time answer is 5.66. I'm looking over things now.

Comment: Hey! You're considering different points for the ball's motion. This means that this is a 3rd method of answering. (it doesn't relate to the 2 methods I'm asking about up there) ... anyways let's solve it your way.

Now your assumption $T = 2t_r+t_1$ seems correct to me. But I can't identify the 2 equations you're using to determine $t_1$

Comment: $s=s+ut-0.5at^2=0$ ???? I think this equation is messed up

Comment: Ok the particle is shot up in the air it travels for $t_r$ seconds, then it will fall again for $t_r$ seconds. But in this fall it will gain the velocity, it had when it was shot up in the air $u$, just negative now!
So it will fall $h=20m$ from that point onwards giving you $s(t) = h-ut-0.5at^2$ and this is supposed to be zero because at height zero it landed!

Comment: well I understand all you're saying and I agree but it's just that equation that doesn't fit in my head!! if you try replacing this equation $s(t)=h−ut−0.5at^2$ with this: $s=ut+0.5at^2$ it would give you $-20=-35sin(45)t-5t^2$ which would give you the quadratic equation $5t^2+35sin(45)t-20=0$ whose positive answer is 0.707 ... input 0.707 to the equation $T = 2t_r+t_1$ and you get 5.66 seconds

Comment: okay I'm stupid I get 0.783 but you're right! XD

Comment: hahahahahaha of course you're not XDD ... anyways it's supposed to be 0.707 . why do you use $s(t)=h−ut−0.5at^2$ instead of the standard $s=ut+0.5at^2$? It even works here!

Comment: its the same just multiply by -1!

Comment: I CAUGHT SOMETHING. You forgot the "5" beside the $t^2$!!!!!! I think that's why you get 0.783 instead of 0.707

Comment: ...allow me to do some editing :) ... and yes it's the same!! didn't notice XD

Comment: no problem!!!!!!